# Elasticsearch get size stats of document given document Id

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 1.4.0

Is there a way to find out the various size stats of a particular document given it's id?

So just to see how ES breaks down each individual document?

Comment: I don't think so. You can see stats at index level and at field level, but not per document.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch has a `_size` field that you can request for a document. In order to use it, you may have to enable it on the mapping for your document type by adding `"_size": {"enabled": true, "store": true}`. There isn't much documentation on its specifics, but it appears to match the total length of the `_source` field for that document. Totaling the `_size` of all documents in an index, however, will **not** match the primary store size for that index. This makes sense, as the underlying lucene indices are storing a tokenized representation of the document, not necessarily its `_source`.

**Example Query:**

```
curl localhost:9200/myIndex/sometype/28c53efe-2eaf-11e5-80c3-000d1fc9a922?fields=_size
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "_index": "myIndex",
    "_type": "sometype",
    "_id": "28c53efe-2eaf-11e5-80c3-000d1fc9a922",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "fields": {
        "_size": 905
    }
}
```